# Returning Iterator vs Loose Coupling

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator

I've got a question about the architecture of a data structure I'm writing. I'm writing an image class, and I'm going to use it in a specific algorithm. In this algorithm, I need to touch every pixel in the image that's within a certain border. The classic way I know to do this is with two nested for loops:

```
for(int i = ROW_BORDER; i < img->height - ROW_BORDER; i++)
    for(int j = COL_BORDER; j < img->width - COL_BORDER; j++)
        WHATEVER
```

However, I've been told that in style of the STL, it is in general better to return an iterator rather than use loops as above. It would be very easy to get an iterator to look at every pixel in the image, and it would even be easy to incorporate the border constraints, but I feel like included the border is blowing loose coupling out of the water.

So, the question is, should I return a special "border-excluding iterator", use the for loops, or is there a better way I haven't thought of?

Just to avoid things like "well, just use OpenCV, or VXL!" , I'm not actually writing an image class, I'm writing a difference-of-gaussian pyramid for use in a feature detector. That said, the same issues apply, and it was simpler to write two for loops than three or four.

Comment: do you want loose coupling between the iterator and yoru class, or between the iterator and the user of the iterator? usually the iterator encapsulates away all kinds of dirty details and is tightly coupled with the data structure

Comment: I meant loose coupling between the class and the algorithm. Data structures should be somewhat independent, right? So, it seems odd to me building in this special-case iterator for a somewhat unique situation. I feel like having a special method "get_bordered_iterator" or something just for this algorithm is not the best style.

Comment: In the case of a 2-d image, I'd just use indexes instead of iterators. [Boost MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) uses indexes as well.

Comment: @anjruu: does the order of pixels matter? if not, it is just some iterator that iterates through all pixels, with unspecified order (from the pov of the iterators user). This seems consistent with e.g. an iterator over a hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have something reusable, I'd go with a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) function.

```
namespace your_imaging_lib {

    template <typename Fun>
    void transform (Image &img, Fun fun) {
        const size_t width = img.width(), 
                     size  = img.height() * img.width();
        Pixel *p = img.data();
        for (size_t s=0; s!=size; s+=width)
        for (size_t x=0; x!=width; ++x)
            p[x + s] = fun (p[x + s]);

    }

    template <typename Fun>
    void generate (Image &img, Fun fun) {
        const size_t width = img.width(), size = img.height();
        Pixel *p = img.data();
        for (size_t s=0, y=0; s!=size; s+=width, ++y)
        for (size_t x=0; x!=width; ++x)
            p[x + s] = fun (x, y);
    }

}
```

Some refinement needed. E.g., some systems like x, y to be in [0..1).

You can then use this like:

```
using namespace your_imaging_lib;
Image i = Image::FromFile ("foobar.png");
map (i, [](Pixel const &p) { return Pixel::Monochrome(p.r()); });
```

or

```
generate (i, [](int x, int y) { return (x^y) & 0xFF; });
```

Iff you need knowledge of both coordinates (x and y), I guarantee this will give better performance compared to iterators which need an additional check for each iteration.

Iterators, on the other hand, will make your stuff usable with standard algorithms, like `std::transform`, and you could make them almost as fast if pixel positions are not needed and you do not have a big pitch in your data (pitch is for alignment, usually found on graphics hardware surfaces).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should be using the visitor pattern instead-- instead of returning an iterator or some sort of collection of your items, you should pass in the operation to be done on each pixel/item to your data structure that holds the items, and the data structure should be able to apply that operation to each item.  Whether your data structure uses for loops or iterators to traverse the pixel/whatever collection is hidden, and the operation is decoupled from the data structure.

Comment: Cool, I've not heard of that before!

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea if you want the best performance. Typically image processing takes a long time and overhead like virtual function calls (especially per-pixel ones!) are better avoided

Comment: Visitor pattern sounds a bit non-typical, regarding that there is no hierarchy but just a single type to visit on. But I am not a pattern lawyer.

Comment: @kotlinski It's not a virtual function call if you use templates; phresnel's answer gives example implementation of visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it sounds like a good idea to have an iterator that touches every pixel. However, it doesn't sound as appealing to me to include the border constraints inside of it. Maybe try to achieve something like:

```
IConstraint *bc=new BorderConstraint("blue-border");
for(pixel_iterator itr=img.begin(); itr!=img.end(); itr++) {
    if(!bc->check(itr))
       continue;
    // do whatever
}
```

Where IConstraint is a base class that can be derived to make many different BorderConstraints.
My rationale is that iterators iterate in different ways but I don't think they need to know about your business logic. That could be abstracted away into another design construct as depcited via Constraints above.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Not required in the above piece of code I guess, a simple BorderConstraint bc; should suffice but assuming that the user will pass a BorderConstraint pointer or refrence to some method that accepts an IConstraint pointer or reference so to be able to specialize on different constraints.

Comment: actually, even if the method access a reference, you don't have to `new` for it. It is necessary to differentiate 3 things in C++: lifetime (`new` means dynamic), copy or not copy and polymorphism. While polymorphism implies no (regular) copy (you can use `clone` methods) it does not imply any specific lifetime policy, such as the use of `new`. *Dynamic allocation and Polymorphism are orthogonal*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know I don't have to new if the method accepts a reference. My point was that the method could accept either a reference or a pointer. If it accepts a pointer, I'd have to new and pass. If a reference than of course no new is 'required'.

Comment: no, even it accepts a pointer you don't have to `new`. Or at least you probably should not, it would be shady for a method to take ownership of a naked pointer. It's way better to advertise such things by accepting a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I didn't say it clearly enough I guess. I meant if the method is accepting the pointer then the caller would call new and pass the pointer. I agree the method shouldn't randomly do a new without doing a delete as well.

Comment: what's wrong with `BorderConstraint b("blue-border"); somemethod(&b);` ? `somemethod` accepts a pointer and yet `BorderConstraint` is an automatic variable. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of bitmap data it is noteworthy that **there are no iterator based algorithms or datasets commonly used in the popular image manipulation APIs.** This should be a clue as to that it is hard to implement as efficiently as a regular 2D array. (thanks [phresnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens))

If you really require/prefer an iterator for your image sans border, you should invent a new concept to iterate. My suggestion would be something like an ImageArea.

```
class ImageArea: Image
{  int clipXLeft, clipXRight;
   int clipYTop, clipYBottom;
  public:
   ImageArea(Image i, clipXTop ... )
```

And construct your iterator from there. The iterators can then be transparent to work with images or regions within an image.

On the other hand, a regular x/y index based approach is not a bad idea. Iterators are very useful for abstracting data sets, but comes with a cost when you implement them on your own.

Comment: *but comes with a cost when you implement them on your own.* There is no special technic when they are implemented by the Standard Library, so the cost will be about the same.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Development cost in general. However, in this case there is a 2D clipping that needs to be considered. 1 - duplicate data to iterate on (mem+copy cost) 2 - calculate the transitions ( it++ cost ).

Comment: what would be hard to implement? `if (++x == width) { x=0; ++y; }`?

Comment: @phresnel yes exactly, a few extra conditions on the ++it. I was not suggesting a flat image area than needed to be magnified/lensed into the extreme =)

Comment: You wrote `This should be a clue as to that it is hard to implement.`, but it isn't. It is just impossible (?) to implement it without a performance penalty.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Good reference to fresnel lenses :D (my nickname is actually based on hobbyist efforts in realistic image synthesis)